# Url Rewrite of Host in ASP.NET on IIS 6

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, url-rewriting

I know this question is overly popular, but I find nothing that addresses rewriting the host, only rewriting the path.

How could I accomplish redirecting/rewriting "http://myHost.com" to "http://myAlias.com/hidden/default.html"?

**ADDED:** where myAlias is just an alias of myHost.

Comment: Do you want to rewrite or redirect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and dirty ... Create a default document for the site (default.aspx for example) to redirect to /hidden/default.html

Comment: Sorry guys, I forgot to include the alias bit.

Answer (score 0):

Along the lines of what James had mentioned with the `default.aspx` in your root.  Then you could rewrite simply..

```
HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("http://myHost.com/hidden/default.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ISAPI-filter in IIS, like **Helicon** to rewrite the document path:

http://www.isapirewrite.com/

The **lite version is free**

---

Edit:
Ok, your want to redirect to another domain. I don't think that Helicon supports that.

You can try (c#):

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("http://myAlias.com/hidden/default.html");
```